# Does an Maximum Likeihood estimator always unique? It is true that an MLE is always unique for exponential family of probability distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, information-theory, maximum-likelihood

The maximum likelihood estimator is the maximizer of the probability distribution for a sample drawn from an unknown distribution.

Is it unique?

If we consider uniform distribution then it is not unique. What will happen if we consider an exponential family of distributions? What is the MLE of the exponential family?

Comment: Maximum likelihood does not maximize the probability distribution. It maximizes the (log-)likelihood (which is a function of the parameters). The MLE of the parameters of the uniform distribution are (usually) unique. There can be multiple MLE, though. For example, take the normal multiple regression model when the data matrix is not full rank.

Comment: There are many ways for this maximum to not be unique. Just imagine for example a probability density that is not log-concave. It is certainly possible to have more than one maximizers.

Comment: Put $3$ balls in an urn, some mixture of red and blue (but unknown how many of each) and draw $2$ with replacement (with a binomial likelihood, so from an exponential family).  What is the maximum likelihood estimate of the number of red balls in the urn if you draw one red and one blue ?

Comment: This question is very strange. You ask about uniqueness of the MLE, and then immediately say that for uniform distributions the MLE is non-unique, and then ask about exponential families. It seems like the concise repharing would be "Is the MLE over an exponential family unique?" - if so, you should edit the question appropriately and remove fluff. bluemaster's answer is appropriate for this question (minus the reference), and you should really try to show the claimed concavity of the log-likelihood.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [article](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/1185/docs/408/NonuniqueMLE.pdf) at The American Statistician addressing the issue you are concerned about:

> Sudhakar Dharmadhikari & Kumar Joag-Dev (1985) Examples of Nonunique
> Maximum Likelihood Estimators, The American Statistician, 39:3,
> 199-200

And yes, the log-likelihood for the exponential family is a concave function, so if there is a solution for the first order conditions, this solution is a global max.